# Passing array of vectors by reference in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In the main function, I defined an array of vectors like this:

```
vector<int> v[n+1];
```

where `n` is taken from stdin.

In the main function, I am calling a function passing this argument like this:

```
   func(v);
```

In the function definition, I defined it this way:

```
func(vector<int>& v[])        # I want to pass v by reference.
```

On compiling using `g++ --std=c++11 a.cpp`, I am getting this error:

```
error: 'v' declared as array of references of type 'vector<int> &'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `vector<int> v[n+1];` is a variable length array, as such it's not legal C++. Why not make things easy for yourself and use a vector of vectors, instead of an array of vectors, like this `vector<vector<int>> v(n+1);`

Comment: Variable length arrays (VLA) are a non-standard construct that is accepted by the g++ compiler but would be rejected by most other C++ compilers. I've no idea if it is possible to pass a VLA to a function by reference because we're not talking about standard C++ any more. But it is definitely possible to pass a vector of vectors to a function by reference, so that's what I recommend that you do.

Comment: Sure, didn't think of it. Thanks for this suggestion. @john

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<int> v[n+1];` where `n` is taken from stdin is illegal C++, even if it's allowed by some compilers as VLA. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

void func(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v);

int main()
{
    int n = 24;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(n);

    func(v1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your motive is to pass an array(dynamic/static) by reference then you could do this :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
template<typename T , std::size_t N>
void fun(T (&v)[N]){
    // do your stuff 
    return ;
}

int main(void){
    std::vector<int>v[100];
    fun(v);
    return 0;
}
```